# $a_1$ is the largest integer satisfying the inequalities $a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}\leq x<a_0+\frac{a_1+1}{10}.$ (Tom M. Apostol "Mathematical Analysis 2nd")

Tags: calculus, soft-question, decimal-expansion

I am reading "Mathematical Analysis 2nd Edition" by Tom M. Apostol.

> ***Theorem 1.20.*** *Assume $x\geq 0.$ Then for every integer $n\geq 1$ there is a finite decimal $r_n=a_0.a_1a_2\cdots a_n$ such that $$r_n\leq x<r_n+\frac{1}{10^n}.$$*
> *Proof.* Let $S$ be the set of all nonnegative integers $\leq x.$ Then $S$ is nonempty, since $0\in S,$ and $S$ is bounded above by $x$. Therefore $S$ has a supremum, say $a_0=\sup S.$ It is easily verified that $a_0\in S,$ so $a_0$ is a nonnegative integer. We call $a_0$ the *greatest integer* in $x$, and we write $a_0=[x].$ Clearly, we have $$a_0\leq x<a_0+1.$$
> Now let $a_1=[10x-10a_0],$ the greatest integer in $10x-10a_0.$ Since $0\leq 10x-10a_0=10(x-a_0)<10,$ we have $0\leq a_1\leq 9$ and $$a_1\leq 10x-10a_0<a_1+1.$$
> In other words, $a_1$ is the largest integer satisfying the inequalities $$a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}\leq x<a_0+\frac{a_1+1}{10}.$$
> $\cdots$

The author wrote

> $a_1$ is the largest integer satisfying the inequalities $$a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}\leq x<a_0+\frac{a_1+1}{10}.$$

Since $\#\{z\in\mathbb{Z}:a_0+\frac{z}{10}\leq x<a_0+\frac{z+1}{10}\}=1,$ and $a_1\in\{z\in\mathbb{Z}:a_0+\frac{z}{10}\leq x<a_0+\frac{z+1}{10}\}$, $a_1$ is certainly the largest integer satisfying the inequalities $$a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}\leq x<a_0+\frac{a_1+1}{10}.$$
So, the author is correct.
But I feel very strange.
Did the author mean the following?

> $a_1$ is the largest integer satisfying the inequality $$a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}\leq x.$$

Comment: I cannot say what the author meant, but the last inequality is sufficient to define $a_1$ uniquely.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Your are right. By the reasoning used in the proof, $a_1$ is clearly unique, so it would be better to write:  

"In other words, $a_1$ is the integer satisfying the inequalities $$a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}\leq x<a_0+\frac{a_1+1}{10}.\text{"}$$

Why Apostol wrote "$a_1$ is the largest integer satisfying ..."?  Quite probably a small "typo" that added the unnecessary word "largest" in the sentence.

Comment: @Ramiro Thank you very much for your answer.